# Why is Hermione at Grimmauld Place during book five?

Tags: harry-potter, hermione-granger, order-of-the-phoenix

Harry goes to 12 Grimmauld Place after the dementor incident to find that the Weasley children and Hermione have been living there along with the Order. From my understanding, the twins, Ron, and Ginny have to be there because their parents are doing Order work, but Hermione's family obviously isn't. And since children aren't allowed to be official Order of the Phoenix members and be let in on things, there doesn't seem to be a reason for Hermione to be there. Is there a reason why she is present there?

Comment: I don't have an actual answer, but I would think it would be because of the story. She seems to spend much of the little time she would have with her parents instead with the Weasleys.

Comment: @Ben that's true. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

### She was spending the rest of her summer vacations *with the Weasleys*, as she did the previous summer

Grimmauld Place was not serving only as the Order's headquarters, but as the Weasleys' temporary home as well, in that particular timeframe.

Don't forget that Harry was neither a member of the Order, yet he went to the Order's headquarters as well to spend his summer vacations. Both he and Hermione went to the place where Ron and his family were staying, to spend their time with their friend -they were not being recruited to a secret brotherhood.

We don't have an exact date on when The Weasleys moved to 12, Grimmauld Place, but that probably happened enough time *before* Harry arrived there:

> “Thanks to you, Dumbledore was able to recall the Order of the Phoenix about **an hour after Voldemort returned**” said Sirius.
>
> <sup>**Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 5 - The Order of the Phoenix**</sup>

Even though we can assume that Dumbledore didn't select Sirius's house that early, the period between that moment and the time Harry arrives is around a month -plenty of time for the Weasleys to move in and for Hermione to join them.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence that Hermione was *"spending the rest of her summer vacations with the Weasleys"*?

Comment: I don't get why you need a written evidence for that. Everyone can infer she went for vacations, what different reason could she have? In the same sense, why she is at the Burrow at the start of Book 6? There's no written evidence either.

Comment: I don't like answers that require me to infer things. If I can infer it one way, someone else can infer it another way. Evidence, on the other hand, is far harder to dispute or ignore.

Comment: @Valorum i too believe in evidence majority of time, but this time the answer makes sense without proof too

Comment: @BabaYaga - In the immortal words of Jerry McGuire, show me the money.

Comment: @Valorum I still don't quite get why inferring this thing is wrong or not favored. The author can't explain in written material every tiny detail. The books never had any mention of the characters taking a shower or using the toilet either. Do we need to post questions for these topics as well and refuse to accept inferring that they were too visiting the bathrooms?

Comment: @Lefteris008 - There are more than a million words in the HP books and close on a million words of interviews and external materials. I think we're really at the point where we don't need to infer anything.

Comment: @Lefteris008 - Hermione "nips into" the toilet in HP5. Harry goes to the toilet on the Hogwarts Express in the same book and Ron goes to the toilet in HP6. Dumbledore talks about going to the loo (in the Room of Requirement), etc etc

Comment: I know this is inferred and not for sure, but right now it sure looks like the best answer that anyone has--and it makes a lot of sense. Thank you.

Comment: I am not going to accept this answer in case if anyone else does have an answer that isn't inferred, though it does seem unlikely

Comment: So, Hermione didn't spend her summer vacations with the Weasleys. In the beginning of book 4, Ron writes "Hermione’s arriving this afternoon" the day before Harry arrives to join them.  In book 6, she arrives two days before Harry: “So Hermione’s here?” he asked happily as he tickled Crookshanks behind the ears. “Oh yes, she arrived the day before yesterday,” said Mrs. Weasley..."

No need to speculate or infer, as the books tell us exactly when Hermione arrives. There's no indication that Hermione *generally* spends her summer vacations with the Weasleys.

Comment: @Athanasius Occam's razor my friend.

Comment: Indeed.  Occam's razor given two other data points directly from the text of the books suggests Hermione does NOT spend her summer vacations "generally" with the Weasleys.  She *generally* arrives a day or two before Harry.

Comment: Whatever you say chief. You can't change my opinion, I can't change yours. We are both *speculating*.

Comment: I'm not sure what's an "opinion" here. You repeatedly implied above there was "no written evidence" to make a determination for your claim. I then provided two book citations that tell us precisely when Hermione arrived. This isn't an "opinion"--it's *stated* when she arrived, which wasn't at the beginning of summer, or near the beginning of summer.  Now, one *could* speculate that Hermione might have come to the Weasleys, spent time there, then went home, then came back a day or two before Harry those two summers.  But that seems to violate Occam's razor as not being the simplest explanation.

Comment: Yes, there's in't a written evidence to back up my claim, as with so many other plot points in the books which are implied but never mentioned. I specifically gave the examples of bathroom, toilet and I can't believe that students never engage in sexual activities (alone or with others), yet we never get **consistent** mentions. Are we to believe that these things never happen? Professors are not mentioned *by name* to have lunch every day, so they are not eating at all? Like I said, there are some common sense facts, which we can only accept as ground truth data.

Comment: As to whether Hermione spent the rest of the vacations there or just arrived two days prior to Harry, but JKR did not think this was *that* important to mention it, we can only make assumptions based on common sense. I am more in favor of the former, as she is showing a consistent behavior from Book 4 onwards, to spend some days with the boys during summer, and go to Hogwarts together. If you don't like my answer, it is acceptable, and I encourage you to write a better one :)